# How to properly swap columns in only two viewports using Bootstrap's PUSH and PULL classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I've got a form tool with two lists and a set of tools between them that is laid out in three columns on larger screens like so...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        AVAILABLE LIST (1)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        MOVEMENT BUTTONS (2)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        SELECTED LIST (3)
    </div>
</div>
```

... as you can see, for the **xs** and **sm** viewports, the layout should switch to a full width stacked list.  What I would like to do is to swap the positions of the `MOVEMENT BUTTONS` and `SELECTED LIST` columns on those smaller view ports so that the tools are the last row (1-2-3 => 1-3-2).

The problem I'm having is that when I add classes like `col-xs-pull-* col-sm-pull-*` to the `SELECTED LIST`, and `col-xs-push-* col-sm-push-*` to the `MOVEMENT BUTTONS` columns, the buttons column dissapears and the selected list is out of alignment.  I've tried corresponding `col-*-push/pull` values of 1 (*because anything should swap them when they're full width, shouldn't they?*) and 12 (*just in case*), both have the same unintended result.

**How can I apply `push/pull` modifier classes to the two columns in question to achieve reordered stacking on `xs` and `sm` viewports?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important thing to realize about Twitter Bootstrap is that they take a mobile-first design mindset. This means that classes that apply to extra-small screens will apply all the way up to large screens unless you overload them.

This is also true for the push and pull classes. So what you need to do is layout the buttons the way you intend for them to be in a small screen and then push/pull them in larger screens to where you want them.

In other words, put the buttons in your HTML where you want them in small screens and use the push/pull medium classes to move them in larger screens.

### Edit

I've created a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bKlVU6nZPb) demonstrating the concept of pushing and pulling. See if that makes sense.

The gist of it is this:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  AVAILABLE LIST (1)
</div>

<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
  SELECTED LIST (3)
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-5">
  MOVEMENT BUTTONS (2)
</div>
```

A push class moves an element to the right a number of columns and the pull class moves an element to the left a number of columns. For example, if you want to switch two elements, the first of size 3 and the second of size 6, you will need to push the first 6 columns and pull the second 3 columns, effectively switching their positions.

Comment: Thanks for that Seth, I guess I had that concept partially in play with the col-sizes but neglected to do the same when it came to the push/pull classes, so good catch!  That said, I'm not exactly sure what classes (specifically which to use push on, which to use pull on, and what sizes) to use, any interest in helping out there so I can accept the answer?  I've looked over the *getboostrap.com* size a dozen times to figure it out, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around their limited examples.

Comment: Edited with a link to an example. Hope that helps!

Comment: Really appreciate the example and the simple explanation, worked like a charm and I've already started spreading the joy to other areas of our code. Cheers!